# Deleted _site folder, now all posts are missing

Tags: jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I run a small blog based on Jekyll in GitHub Pages. Trying to fix an error at rebuilding it, I deleted the `_site` folder, which made all posts disappear from it.

It's rebuilding the site now, great, but it shows no posts at all — even that all of them are in `_posts` folder.

What am I missing here?

For reference: https://github.com/rghedin/rghedin.github.io

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_site` folder contains the generated files, it is not necessary to have them in the repo as github pages will build it.

If you deleted it and now there are no posts showing at the homepage, then there should be another error, try to run a local instance to debug it or wait for github pages to rebuild it and show the latest version, it could take some minutes to show the latest changes online.

Comment: You're right! Problem was at index.html code. As soon I removed this parte (which, weirdly, was working fine until last commit), everything worked as expected. Thanks for your attention!